# Class casting going wrong?

Tags: java, reflection

Alright. I am working on some reflection for my java program, but I am stuck on a part that seems simple, but just doesn't work.

Here is what I am attempting to do:

```
Thread t = new Thread();
System.out.println("Casting "+Thread.class.getName()+" to "+Runnable.class.getName());
Object newThread = Runnable.class.cast(t);
System.out.println("New class: "+newThread.getClass().getName());
```

The expected output would be 
`New class: java.lang.Runnable`, however, it returns `New class: java.lang.Thread`.

What am I doing wrong? (And note that I can't use normal casting via brackets in this case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must understand what casting is with object reference types.  Like normal casting, [`Class`'s `cast` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) does not change the actual type of the object.  It yields a reference variable of the appropriate type that refers to the object, which is not changed.

The `Thread` `t` is still a `Thread`.  The cast actually works, because [`Thread` implements `Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), otherwise a `ClassCastException` would have been thrown.  But it's still a `Thread`.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I fixed my problem, but the actual problem lied somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Here's how Thread class is defined:

```
public class Thread
extends Object
implements Runnable
```

So an object that is an instance of Thread class would still return its class name as Thread even though you cast it as Runnable.